# Is $f(x)=-2/(x+c)$ the only solution to $f''=f'f$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Given the equation $\displaystyle f''=f'f$, I came up with the solution $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{-2}{x+c}\; c\in \mathbb{R}$ as follows.

$$f''=ff'\implies 2\int f''=\int 2ff'\iff2f'=f^2\implies \frac{f'}{f^2}=\frac{1}{2}\implies\int -\frac{f'}{f^2} = -\int \frac{1}{2}\implies \left(\frac{1}{f}\right)(x)=\frac{-x-c}{2}$$
$$\implies f(x)=-\frac{2}{x+c}\;\; c\in\mathbb{R}$$

Is there a way to know if this is the only solution? Is my process correct? I know nothing about differential equations, I sort of just thought of this one and decided to give it a go (I mention this so that the answers take that into account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you missed the red $C$: $$f''=ff'\implies 2\int f''=\int 2ff'\iff2f'=f^2 + \color{red}C$$ Then you have $$ \frac{d f}{d x} = \frac{1}{2}f^2 + \color{red}C \\ \frac{df}{\frac{f^2}{2}+\color{red}C} = dx$$
Now, integrate.

**Added:** As you said you are new to ODE, I will finish the work this time.

You have found the solution when $\color{red}C = 0$, and the other case is as follows:
$$ \int\frac{df}{\frac{f^2}{2}+\color{red}C} = \int dx \\ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\color{red}C}}\arctan\left(\frac{f}{2\color{red}C}\right)  = x + C$$ Now, you can find $f$ from the last equality if you wish or just leave it as it.